# How to increase the width of Cover block in Gutenberg Editor,Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, width, wordpress-gutenberg, column-width, cover

How to increase the width of Cover Block in Gutenberg Editor in WordPress? The background colour of the block is widening to full width, but the Block width is not widening corresponding to the width of background.

Full Width option is not applicable to the block,as the cover contains columns in it.

I tried to expand the width to Full.The Cover Block background width did go to Full,but there was no option to widen the Cover Block with it's content (Mainly Columns) to full width of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom stylesheet file to your dashboard and override any default styles.

Take a look at this answer for an example:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44753/wordpress-admin-stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Try adding custom CSS to your theme to widen the content within the Cover Block. By adjusting the width of the columns and the overall container, you can align the block's content with its background.